# How to draw multiple triangle in OpenGL C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

I was able to get to draw a single object with an array of vertices. However, it gave me a hard time when it comes to draw multiple objects.

I have an array of data like this and three vertices render one triangle:

```
-0.0570917f,0.490469f,-0.142433f
-0.0581126f,0.5f,-0.160615f
-0.0651903f,0.490827f,-0.147409f
-0.0501295f,0.499886f,-0.158146f
-0.0491703f,0.49039f,-0.140236f
-0.0422027f,0.499864f,-0.157942f
-0.041255f,0.49031f,-0.138206f
-0.0333885f,0.490314f,-0.137995f
-0.0967512f,0.48302f,-0.150394f
...
```

And I am trying to render multiple triangles with the following code:

```
// this array contains arrays with one vertex (three elements)
vector<vector<GLfloat>> pointVertex;

// Render OpenGL here
for (int i = 0; i < pointVertex.size(); i++) {
    vector<GLfloat> temp = pointVertex[i];
    GLfloat *pointVertexArrayPoint = temp.data();
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, pointVertexArrayPoint);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, temp.size());
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
}
```

Now, I am getting a result but it all starts at the same point. I want it to render different multiple separate triangles. How can I change it?

Comment: @Brandon Do you want to form an answer? Looks like you have a clue on how to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. I guess you want to render three lines for each triangle? From vertex 0 to 1, 1 to 2 and 2 to 0? Currently you pass the pointer to one vertex and then tell OpenGL to read 3 vertices from it. You're at least reading outside of your memory for the last two iterations.

Comment: @BDL. I want to render multiple independent triangles. And three vertices forms one.

Comment: But why are you then drawing `GL_LINES` if you want to draw triangles?

Comment: @BDL, I clearly don't know what I am doing. I changed but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this without straying away from the technique you are using (Legacy pipeline)..

The below code will draw two triangles.. like so:

[image]

Each triangle is rendered with 1 draw call per triangle:

```
void onDisplayRefreshSO(void* ctx)
{
    //Setup OpenGL once..
    static std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once(flag, []{
        GLfloat view_port[4] = {0};
        glGetFloatv(GL_VIEWPORT, &view_port[0]);
        GLfloat screen_width = view_port[2] - view_port[0];
        GLfloat screen_height = view_port[3] - view_port[1];

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        gluPerspective(45.0, screen_width / screen_height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
        glClearDepth(1.0f);                                    // Depth Buffer Setup
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enables Depth Testing
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                                // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
        glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);    // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    });



    /** Setup Drawing Triangles **/
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);


    GLfloat normals[] = {
        0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1
    };

    GLfloat colors[] = {
        1, 1, 1,   1, 1, 0,   1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1,   0, 1, 0,   0, 0, 1
    };

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        1, 1, 1,  -1, 1, 1,  -1,-1, 1,
        1, 1, 1,  1, -1, 1,  -1,-1, 1
    };



    //9 floats per triangle.. 3 * (X, Y, Z)..
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]) / 9; ++i)
    {
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals + (i * 9));
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors + (i * 9));
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices + (i * 9));

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-1.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); //3 vertices (X, Y, Z) per triangle..
        glPopMatrix();

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

All triangles rendered in a single draw call:

```
void onDisplayRefreshSO2(void* ctx)
{
    //Setup OpenGL once..
    static std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once(flag, []{
        GLfloat view_port[4] = {0};
        glGetFloatv(GL_VIEWPORT, &view_port[0]);
        GLfloat screen_width = view_port[2] - view_port[0];
        GLfloat screen_height = view_port[3] - view_port[1];

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        gluPerspective(45.0, screen_width / screen_height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            // Enable Smooth Shading
        glClearDepth(1.0f);                                    // Depth Buffer Setup
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            // Enables Depth Testing
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                                // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
        glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);    // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    });


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);


    /** Setup Drawing Triangles **/
    GLfloat normals[] = {
        0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1,   0, 0, 1
    };

    GLfloat colors[] = {
        1, 1, 1,   1, 1, 0,   1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1,   0, 1, 0,   0, 0, 1
    };

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        1, 1, 1,  -1, 1, 1,  -1,-1, 1,
        1, 1, 1,  1, -1, 1,  -1,-1, 1
    };


    //Draw both triangles in a single call..
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-1.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0])) / 3); //6 vertices (X, Y, Z) for 2 triangles..
    glPopMatrix();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add *index buffer*. See sample: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ru/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/

The pipeline:

1. Fill vertex and index buffers
2. Draw buffers

Comment: Thanks, @toodef. Do you think I need to change my data structure or it's okay to use my current one?

Comment: Using indices wouldn't change anything here.